# How do I setup a rule in web.config to rewrite to a subdirectory/file in IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, web-config, url-rewriting

I am having an issue trying to get the rewrite working in IIS7 web.config.

I need URLs like /err/interaccess to be rewritten to /err/404new.asp (not a redirect,as I don't want to expose the file.

I tried the following and it only works if I use /interaccess but not /err/interaccess

```
           <rule name="Rewrite Interaccess Error" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^tinteraccess$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/err/404new.asp" />
            </rule>
```

Any idea on why?  I tried to find documentation on this and could not find anything regarding this usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic is in the regular expression of the `<match>` tag. To make it match your exact URL you would use:

```
       <rule name="Rewrite Interaccess Error" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^err/interaccess$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/err/404new.asp" />
        </rule>
```

If you would want to match everything under `/err/` you would use:

```
      <rule name="Rewrite Interaccess Error" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^err/" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/err/404new.asp" />
        </rule>
```

This is all very well documented, e.g.: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite (see Related Learning)

Comment: Thanks! That is what I thought I had done originally but something probably went wrong. I appreciate the code as I could just start over and get it working (which it is doing flawlessly.) However, even more important was the documentation link! Thanks again!